# maven 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: windows, linux, apache, maven, command-line

Every time I run mvn clean install on any project I build, I always come across 5-6 pom files that contain this:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/0.6.39</center>
</body>
</html>
```

This also means that the jar is only 1 KB and contains nothing in it. I can fix this by going to search.maven.org and finding the pom and .jar and redownloading both. Is there a solution to this issue? I hate having to do this every time. On my linux environment I don't see this issue but on windows it appears more than normal.
Thanks,
Steve.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like one of your repositories is not working correctly. In particular the message nginx means you don't use a repository manager. If you are behind a proxy that might be the problem.

Comment: Could I have a kind of "fall-back" repository where if it fails to find the .jar, it will switch to another repository? I am not behind any proxy and I turned off my firewall to see if that was the issue, but still the same issue. The weird issue is that this works in ubuntu with exact same settings, but in windows(7) it fails.